# r xtable and table of frequencies, printing rowwise

Tags: r, row, xtable

`xtable` doesn't know at the moment how to print tables of frequencies from `base::table`. What I do now is I convert it to a dataframe and then I change the headings using `colnames` as needed:

```
dset <- data.frame(rpois(100, 1))
dset.print <- as.data.frame(table(dset))
colnames(dset.print) <- c("smth", "freq")
xtable(dset.print)
```

Now, what I'd like is to print this table rowwise (like the actual output of `table(dset)` with the headings at the front). I tried something like this

```
dset.print <- t(as.matrix(table(dset)))
dset.print <- cbind(c("smth", "freq"), as.data.frame(dset.print))
```

But this didn't exactly give what I wanted.

Comment: Would you consider using kable() or pander()?  The output from pander() looks pretty good in HTML, PDF and MS Word.  It doesn't require changing the print "type", as is required by xtable in my answer below.  The absence of column names does look a little funny in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty good if you're knitting to PDF. If you're knitting to MS Word or HTML, specify *print(dset.xtab, type="html")*  You may not find the aesthetics of those as nice.

````
```{r xtable, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(xtable)

dset <- data.frame(rpois(100, 1))

dset.print <- as.data.frame(table(dset))
dset.print <- rbind.data.frame(as.character(dset.print[,1]), dset.print[,2])
names(dset.print) <- rep('', ncol(dset.print))
rownames(dset.print) <- c('smth', 'freq')

dset.xtab <- xtable(dset.print)

print(dset.xtab)

```
````

Comment: Priority is pdf output, so it's fine. Actually, I found out that I could directly transpose the above data frame (all the data are just coerced to char) if the goal is just to print the table. Thanks. By the way, there should be no need to coerce `dset.print[ ,1]`

Comment: Actually, one needs to coerce `dset.print[, 1]`. I didn't expect this behavior!

Comment: I believe dset.print[, 1] contains the bin labels...  you're calling them `smth`, right?  They start out as factors.  If you don't coerce them, you could really get confused because the factor numbers will be returned.  In this case, the smth factors at {1,2,3...} and the bins from the poisson distribution are {0,1,2...}